# Error on sxa watch [Cannot read property 'jsPath' of undefined]

Tags: sxa, creative-exchange, sxa-cli

I set up my project with Creative Exchange Live using SXA CLI, the command "sxa build" works but when I try to use "sxa watch" or "sxa upload" I have this below.

I checked the path of my online project and the path of the theme but it's good...
I tried to reinstall sxa/celt and all the node modules but nothing works...
Do you have an idea what this error means ?

Thanks!

````
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({
  uid: 6,
  name: 'watchMapJs',
  branch: false,
  error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsPath' of undefined
      at watchMapJs (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\@sxa\celt\tasks\watchMapJs.js:15:33)
      at bound (domain.js:421:15)
      at runBound (domain.js:432:12)
      at asyncRunner (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
    domainThrown: true
  },
  duration: [ 0, 15498300 ],
  time: 1639650824814
})
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:389:17)
    at Gulp.emit (domain.js:475:12)
    at Object.error (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\createExtensions.js:61:10)
    at handler (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\now-and-later\lib\map.js:50:14)
    at f (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at f (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\async-done\index.js:24:15)
    at done (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\async-done\index.js:40:12)
    at Domain.onError (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\async-done\index.js:51:5) {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR',
  context: {
    uid: 6,
    name: 'watchMapJs',
    branch: false,
    error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsPath' of undefined
        at watchMapJs (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\@sxa\celt\tasks\watchMapJs.js:15:33)
        at bound (domain.js:421:15)
        at runBound (domain.js:432:12)
        at asyncRunner (C:\Users\name\Desktop\Repositories\Project\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
      domainThrown: true
    },
    duration: [ 0, 15498300 ],
    time: 1639650824814
  }
}```
````